# Outlook UI blocked by "digitaloptout.com" dialog

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Recently my Outlook (connected to a 1and1.com exchange server) has been showing a modal dialog "Contacing: \fp130.digitaloptout.com". This dialog stays up for multiple seconds.

It does this every couple of times when I do something such as select a message in the UI or send a message. While this dialog is up, I can't access the Outlook UI. Google is not telling me anything useful about this. I have not changed settings recently.

Anyone know specifically what this "digitaloptout" is? Anyone know how I can stop seeing this darn dialog all the time?

Thanks.

Edit1: Not a hotmail sender problem for me, but I'll try to double check if I only see this with a set of senders.

Edit2: Yeah, it is a digitaloptout.com 1x1 pixel image in the footer of a single sender's email. I just had so many emails from her that the problem seemed pervasive.
Thanks.

Comment: This is why Outlook blocks images by default...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this when opening an email message:

[image: Error Message]

I found the following injected below the signature of an email I received. You can find it by clicking "View Source" on the culprit message.

```
<img border=0 width=1 height=1 id="_x0000_i1027" src="//fp130.digitaloptout.com/acttr?p=YTQyNjgzNzY5NzCRcH1wgePwyXUym5UMQLdKsha931jRGJ95%2F7DX13MF3GbCGTfWuuCECAWbiBZxe4W4SJR%2BbcW116R3EJ7sRe%2BSJninXXYyeSJ3CpHGyEbvyl3gtvl%2BxV%2FSQKjD1ZeLCR4sj8%2B05wc8kvG1j1X8HjdaWLJrqUaT1JVEbAjGntdx3g%3D%3D&amp;m=FP30_%3A_alreadyInjected_%3A_FP30_%3A_FP30&amp;t=1410561589634">
```

It looks like this ad company got a 1x1 pixel invisible image embedded into the thread. Once the email thread is deleted, the problem goes away. From what I can tell, it is a domain of Future Ads LLC out of Irvine, CA, and it probably wouldn't hurt to have your IT dept block all traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a user running Win 7 Pro 64, Office 2013 Pro Plus, connecting to our exchange server natively getting the exact same pop-up for the past week.  No infections found from either Symantec Endpoint or MalwareBytes Corporate.

I found a similar issue at this [microsoft answers url](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/opening-outlook-2010-i-get-a-message-contacting/a3368c61-e72c-4756-8a5f-eac6b9171700)

They're saying that there is a particular email with the link that is causing it and simply deleting it is what is needed to resolve the popup.

Outlook has to be ran in safe mode to avoid the popup, search for the email and delete it.

-Click on Start and type:  outlook.exe /safe  (press enter)
-Search for digitaloptout.com and delete the email(s)
-Check your Add-ins too while you're in there
-Click on File > Options > Add-Ins > See if anything looks questionable in the Active Add-Ins

If the search doesn't find it, delete any and all unnecessary emails that came in the day that you 1st started getting the popups.

### --

Following up:  the user with the popups did not find "digitaloptout.com" in any emails while in safemode.  He found it in regular mode, in a couple of emails sent to him by one of his students (I do IT support for a university).  Emails have been deleted and the problem on his computer is now resolved.